# USing Azure partition key with "Starts with"

Tags: azure, azure-storage, nosql

I have my a Azure table where the partition key is,

```
Partition Key- customerId|DepartmentId, where DepartmentId is a random guid

Eg- 1000|efffoooLopefrmetr008
```

Now I need to get all the customers whose partition key starts with a specific customerId

I have tried for a customerId = 1000

```
Partition Key ge "1000"
Partition Key le "1000"
```

But nothing seems to work correctly. It brings many other entries along with the matching entry.
 Is there any simple solution that works ?

Comment: What kind of behavior you're seeing? When you say `nothing seems to work` what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you also give an example of your DepartmentId? Also, are you using `/` in your PartitionKey? How are you separating Customer Id and Department Id in your PartitionKey?

Comment: I am using '|' to store the value in Azure table. So for eg it will be like '1000|56'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, if you want to get records for a customer with a specific id, you would need to do something like:

```
PartitionKey ge '1000|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' and PartitionKey le '1000|FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

Essentially you would need to specify a range of PartitionKeys to fetch.

**UPDATE**

Come to think about it, you need not specify entire GUID. You can also try by just specifying the following:

```
PartitionKey ge '1000|0' and PartitionKey le '1000|F'
```

This should also work.

Comment: But I my department Id happens to be a GUID unfortunately. Any way I can handle that ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Depending on how you're formatting your GUID, you would essentially need to specify entire range (from all 0's to all F's). HTH.

Comment: I just updated my answer (again :)). Can you please see if the update works for you as well?

Comment: Awesome! I realized it later on and so I thought I should include it as well :). In fact this is how we're doing it in our application as well.